# Is there any way for generics themselves to take type parameters in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

Let's say I have a function with the following signature:

`<T> T f(List<T> a, T b)`

Obviously, I can do the following:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int x = 0;
int y = f(list, x);
```

However, I am not allowed to do this:

```
List<List<?>> list = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> y = f(list, x);
```

In that case, what I would want is a signature something like this:

`<T, V> T<V> foo(List<T<?>>, T<V> x)`

However, there is two problems with this. First of all, Java simply doesn't let me do that, citing `Type 'T' does not have type parameters`. Secondly, I assume the first scenario I described as possible would no longer be possible.

So, my question is: is there any way to write a function with a signature that allows for both of the above scenarios?

Comment: You can write `<V, T extends List<V>>` but I what is `f` supposed to do with the values, and what is it supposed to return?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<T> T f(List<? super T> a, T b)
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain. It isn't clear why using `super` solves the problem.

Comment: This answer does exactly what I want it to, though. I think I also know why from context. But yeah, it probably should have an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do that. This compiles:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> y = f(list, x); // T is List<Integer>
```

If you want a separate method that handles Lists of `T`:

```
<T> List<T> fList(List<List<T>> a, List<T> b)

List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> z = fList(list, x); // T is Integer
```

Comment: The thing is, I want one method that handles both. I would be writing the same code in each method, plus I can't even overload them because they register as having the same signature.

Comment: @Captain_D1 it *already* handles both! See top code block, which compiles.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did now. But what if I need the list to be of type `List<List<?>>`? What you wrote wouldn't work if I need the list to hold a `List<Integer>` *and* a `List<Double>`.

Comment: Oh, a "mixed bag" list. Does simply `<T> T f(List<?> a, T b)` work for you?